# UIPopoverController for iphone in ios8 shows white screen

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, uipopovercontroller

Using UIPopovercontroller below ios8.0 in iphone working fine with this code. But in ios8 it display white screen.

Code :

```
pickerController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIView *viewV = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 160)];
[viewV setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
popOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:pickerController];
popOverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(150, 160);
[popOverController setDelegate:self];

CGRect ImageBtnFrame = [self.view convertRect:sender.frame fromView:self.view];       
[popOverController presentPopoverFromRect:ImageBtnFrame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Any alternative for ios8, need suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the new iOS 8 API for popovers.

```
pickerController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIView *viewV = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 160)];
[viewV setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

UIPopoverPresentationController *popOverController = pickerController .popoverPresentationController;
popOverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(150, 160);
[popOverController setDelegate:self];

popOverController.sourceView = self.view;
popOverController.sourceRect = sender.frame;
popOverController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp;

[self presentViewController:popOverController
                     animated:YES
                   completion:nil];
```

Comment: `[self presentViewController:popOverController animated:YES completion:nil];` gives an warning: `Incompatible pointer types sending 'UIPopoverPresentationController *' to parameter of type 'UIViewController * _Nonnull'`

Answer (score 11):

According to [2014 WWDC](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014-214/), in the 30 minute mark, the right answer is:

```
- (void) tapButton:(id) sender
{
    MyViewControllerClass * vc = [[MyViewControllerClass alloc] init];
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;

    UIPopoverPresentationController * popOverController = vc.popoverPresentationController;
    [popOverController setDelegate:self];
    popOverController.sourceView = sender;
    popOverController.sourceRect = ((UIButton*)sender).frame;
    popOverController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp;

    [self presentViewController:vc
                       animated:YES
                     completion:nil];
}
```

Notice that the accepted answer has some problems like:

- Not setting the `modalPresentationStyle`
- Presenting the `UIPopoverPresentationController *` instead of the `UIViewController`

Comment: Yes, you are right. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

That will cause on iOS 8. So, I recommended to use following Github library.
https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0 or you can write code base on iOS version.

```
    if (OLDER_THAN_IOS_8) {
       // Your regular code
       pickerController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
       UIView *viewV = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 160)];
       [viewV setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
       popOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:pickerController];
       popOverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(150, 160);
       [popOverController setDelegate:self];

      CGRect ImageBtnFrame = [self.view convertRect:sender.frame fromView:self.view];       
      [popOverController presentPopoverFromRect:ImageBtnFrame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];

    } else {

     // New Code that support iOS -8 using UIPopoverPresentationController
     // Checkout @AndreasZ answer for the same
    }
```